# Should I use Client-side fetching on component mount after using getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I think using client-side fetching is an overkill, after using getServerSideProps in Next-js,
i feel if i prerenderd the data already shuld i again fetch the data on component render.

I dont know what is the best approach for this kind of problem if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a personal choice than a "right or wrong".

In the docs, Vercel notes this:

> You should use getServerSideProps only if you need to render a page
> whose data must be fetched at request time. This could be due to the
> nature of the data or properties of the request (such as authorization
> headers or geo location). Pages using getServerSideProps will be
> server side rendered at request time and only be cached if
> cache-control headers are configured.
>
> If you do not need to render the data during the request, then you
> should consider fetching data on the client side or getStaticProps.

- [Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops)

If the data is blog or post based, and doesn't require auth (or is account based), then you could use [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)

You also have to think of the size of the data. Vercel recommends under 128kb. - [Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/large-page-data)

The way I go about picking the right choice is

1. Is the data needed on load?
2. How big is this data?
3. Is it auth based?
4. How frequently does this data change?

As always, there are multiple ways to do the same thing in Nextjs and I think you need to decide what is the best for the use case, and user experience. Do you want to risk load time to ensure the the data on render? Or is having only the main data loaded then client-side fetching on a few components okay?

Comment: so this basically means that client-side fetching on render will ensure that the data is up to date, more than the getServerSideProps, and if the data isn't frequently changing I should use ISR instead of getServerSideProps